# How to get Win-n Unity shortcut keys in Kubuntu?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, launcher, plasma

I got pretty used to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc shortcut keys from Unity and I'd like to know if there's some way to emulate this in KDE Plasma.

Right now I'm using KDE Plasma 5.13.5, running on Kubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Please see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSBMn6eGH88. However, the numbers don't appear at least on Plasma 5.12. There are other videos as well such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd5y7m9q3yg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1i7jAtHcw4. But these vids maybe a bit different than what you see because KDE Plasma is being developed rapidly.

Comment: To be informed of progress please look at https://pointieststick.com/2019/02/10/this-week-in-usability-productivity-part-57/ etc and https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/new/ but note that most features described are for the latest version of KDE Plasma, available in KDE neon which unfortunately is off-topic at Ask Ubuntu.